# String .contains another String

Tags: java, string, user-interface, arraylist

So I have an `arraylist` and a `string`. I have to compare whether the arraylist contains the string. I did `"ArrayList.toString()"` to convert it to string since I can't compare an arraylist with a string. And then I proceeded to use `.contains`. It sort of works.

For example, let's say if String 1= "ground" and in String 2 the word "playground" exists, then it would make the .contains true because the word "ground" is inside the word "playGROUND". Is there anyway to avoid this? The arraylist had some first letters caps so I set it .tolowercase so everything could be uniform. I've tried .equals and .equalsIgnorecase and no luck. :/

Comment: Hard to understand what all you have written here?

Comment: You may need to iterate over the list and check each item against the word

Comment: I recommend you posting some code, also, can you use a for loop ? Simply compare the strings one by one ...

Comment: arraylist.toString() doesn't do what you think it does http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractCollection.html#toString()

Comment: If you are iterating over the words, you should use equals() or equalsIgnoreCase() depending on your use case

Answer (score 1):

> i have to compare whether the arraylist contains the string. i did
>   "ArrayList.toString()" to convert it to string since i cant compare an
>   arraylist with a string.

You can also use `contains` method on `ArrayList<String>`

> for example, lets say if String 1= "ground" and in String 2 the word
>   "playground" exists, then it would make the .contains true because the
>   word "ground" is INSIDE the word "playGROUND". Is there anyway to
>   avoid this?

Yes use `contains` method of arrayList it will not return true for `ground` if it has `playGround`.

> Ive tried .equals and .equalsIgnorecase and no luck :/

You have to loop over the arrayList and than use `equalsIgnorecase` on each `String` to find the match.

Comment: I'm glad you could understand what he was talking about for his 3rd part plus a good explanation. +1

Answer (score 0):

**Question 1:**

Iterate through your list and compare each value to the string for comparison.

```
for(string temp: yourList)
   if(temp.equals(stringForCompare))
       //true
//false
```

**Question 2:**

`if(string2.contains(string1) && !string2.equals(string1))` is the logic you are explaining in your question which makes no sense and can be simplified to `if(!string2.equals(string1)`.

**Question 3:**

Not even sure what you're asking but @TAsk has it pretty well answered it looks.